# Build a program setup with dependencies to other programs

Tags: windows, google-chrome, installation, setup-project, installation-package

I come from the *nix world but my next task is to build up a Windows application. Since I am new to Win's world I am wondering if the following scenario is possible and in case how to achieve it:

I would like that my program, during the setup, will check if Google Chrome is installed and if not, having the Chrome binaries of the version I wish to use embedded in the setup, force its installation. Then when everything is installed I would like to have an icon on the desktop that calls Chrome with the parameters to load my pages (will be an offline application).

I really don't know if this scenario is possible. Any help would be appreciated :)

Enrico

Comment: Windows, as you have noted and much to its long term detriment, does not have a standard package manager. So each thing you need to detect needs to be detected in a thing specific way.

Comment: yes I know, in fact the idea is to check whether Chrome is installed and in case is not install it having a chrome setup executable embedded into my setup. Pretty much like when you install games it installs the right DirectX version in case they are missing in the system